# Is any way to create template in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have to create a similar type of package. i have created on of them. Now  i want to use all variable and all control flow task and data flow task are used in previously package. Is it any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it is:

1. Find the .dtsx file, copy it with a new name like Template.DTSX
2. Put it in a different folder to your project
3. Go into your project and 'Add Existing Package'

You now have a copy of your package.

Repeat using your new template package at step 1 when you need to create a new package.

You might also want to do some research on BIML as this is a way to auto create packages.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Nick McDermaid's answer but I always stored mine in the same location that [Visual Studio looks for them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345191.aspx).

Assuming a 64 bit architectures, those paths would be

- SSIS 2005 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject`
- SSIS 2008 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject`
- VS 2010, SSIS 2012 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\DataTransformationItems 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject`
- VS 2012, SSIS 2012 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\DataTransformationItems 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject`
- SSIS 2014 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\DataTransformationItems 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject`

Create your masterpiece, mine's called `IAmTemplate.dtsx` and copy it to that protected folder. If you have UAC still on, you'll be prompted before you can save it there.

### How do I use it

If you right click on the "SSIS Packages" folder, you'll only see `New SSIS Package` and that won't be useful

[image]

Instead, you'll want to click at the Project level and choose Add New Item

[image]

Then in the resulting window, you should see any templates you've defined plus the options specified by DtsProjectItems.vsdir file in the above locations

[image]

Hooray, I now have a template

[image]

However, you're not done yet. You have a verbatim copy of the Template package. That's fine, until you try to do any analysis of packages by their PackageID. In the normal route of creating a package, you get a unique ID for every package but when you copy paste a package, that doesn't get regenerated so you're stuck doing it manually.

[image]

I usually leave an annotation in the templates reminding future authors of this step

[image]

The 2012 release of SSIS addressed the copy paste not generating new ID but I don't know if it did so for the template approach as well. You can also use [Bids Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) to reset all the package GUIDS at a go.